# Applying two type rotation on one object

Tags: animation

I want this object to rotate around itself while rotates according to the path but the two rotate affect each other and the object has an unorder movement on the path. please help me what should to do

Thank you

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: pls copy paste images right here in the question. don't use external links because if they get deleted, your question becomes useless for everybody else, thx

Comment: I have been confused I post the images directly but receive an error

Comment: Hello and welcome. Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [GIF](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963)

Comment: Thank you I got it  :)

Comment: Enable the Follow Curve option of the constraint, and make the object rotate on itself with some keyframes, if it doesn't work please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: I understood approximately but now I don't know what to do. You are right, it is not similar to a regular forum that I was familiar with. I found the StackExchenge website by chance. Please do whatever is necessary, but before that, please enlighten me, how can I upload a Blender file here Thank you so much

Comment: Have you clicked the blend-exchange link in @moonboots comment? Once in there, just follow the instructions.

Comment: If you are unable to use blend-exchange, you can always use another service of your choosing like google drive or whatever. Just do not use file sharing services that limit download speed and require to wait to be able to start downloading.